# Why data transfer slowing down after a while in socket communication?

Tags: c++, opencv, sockets

I'm trying to send desktop's screenshot to the server over a TCP socket. At first, everything is fine and i get like 30FPS. But after a while it slows down, is there any specific reason for that ?

Server code:

```
    while(!is_client_dead){

    char file_size[1024];

    recv(m_video_socket,file_size,1024,0);

    char *data = new char[std::atoi(file_size)];

    recv(m_video_socket,data,std::atoi(file_size),0);
    
    std::fstream file("screenshot.png",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);

    for(int x{0};x<std::atoi(file_size);x++)
        file << data[x];

    delete [] data;

    file.close();

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("screenshot.png");

    cv::resize(image,image,cv::Size(image.cols/2,image.rows/2));

    cv::imshow(m_name + "'s screen",image);

    cv::waitKey(1);

}
```

Client code:

```
        while(!is_server_dead){

        cv::Mat image;

        capture_screen(image);

        cv::imwrite("screenshot.png",image);

        std::size_t size = std::filesystem::file_size("screenshot.png");
        
        send(m_client_video,std::to_string(size).c_str(),1024,0);

        std::ostringstream file_buffer; 
        
        std::fstream file("screenshot.png",std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

        file_buffer << file.rdbuf();

        std::string file_data = file_buffer.str();

        send(m_client_video,file_data.c_str(),size,0);

        file.close();

    }
```

I thought maybe the problem was memory leak so I tried to delete the data in each loop. I'm also closing the file. What could be the reason of slowing down ?

Comment: Whether this is the problemm you're trying to resolve or not, this code is doomed because it does not inspect and handle the return values from  `recv` and `send`. They return utterly vital information that you cannot successfully do without.

Comment: Side note: Rather than `new`ing the buffer and later `delete` ing it, use a `std::vector`. `vector` handles pretty much every failure case that's not immediately fatal for you with no mus and no fuss.

Comment: @user4581301 i know, rest of the code has proper error checks. I dont have any problem with send and recv's behaviour. It has to do something with rest of the code.

Comment: Avoid using `atoi`. There are to many failure cases that you can't trap effectively (and sometimes can't trap at all). Consider using `std::stoi`  or `std::from_chars` instead.

Comment: Ignoring the return value from `recv()` and `send()` always ends in tears. And feeding something that is ***not*** 0-terminated to `atoi` always ends in tears, too. Those are the first two fundamental bugs that seem to be quite apparent, there might be more...

Comment: You don't have any problem **that you know of**. You do have a problem, though. For example, you can't be certain that `recv(m_video_socket,file_size,1024,0);` got exactly the right number of bytes. The read could end too soon to contain the complete number and force `atoi` to fail. It  could read in and subsequently discard part of the image file. You cannot write this code without the checks. Period.

Comment: The code doesn't properly recv data, it doesn't do framing correctly. If it happens that a single file comes in two packets the what you get? You read first packet, and interpret the second one as file_size. At that point you are completely out of sync, recving random bytes, interpreted as random data. In theory this can lead to millions invalid recv and disk io calls.

Comment: Actually, the byte count is not `\0` terminated on the sending side, @user4581301 -- now look what's happening on the receive side... Think about what's getting fed into `atoi`...

Comment: Remember that TCP is a stream. It gleefully buffers up data from multiple calls to `send` , fragments messages into multiple packets, and generally makes a complete mockery of your data format. **you the programmer** need to preserve the format by being very explicit.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I admit to looking no further than the ignored return values because that one mistake cooked the goose.

Comment: Here's a good place to refresh your knowledge of network programming: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ .